# DB2 error on TSQL using SELECT AS alias and an inner join

Tags: t-sql, select, db2, syntax-error

I am writing a T-SQL program over a DB2 database on a LINUX box (DB2/LINUXX8664) using a linked server. I think the DB2 is Version 9.5.3 but not certain. I am receiving an error that I feel is likely a DB2 issue as the syntax checks out okay in T-SQL. This is the code:

```
IF(SELECT(OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TempFile))) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempFile

SELECT        *

INTO  #TempFile
FROM  OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, '

SELECT  F.LOAN_NUMBER,

   (SELECT 
    SUM(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + 
    SUM(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT)+
    SUM(EXP_USER_1_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + 
    SUM(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT)
    FROM FINANCIAL F)
       AS ExpenseTotal,

    (SELECT
     SUM(MORTGAGOR_NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + SUM(MORTGAGOR_OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) AS IncomeTotal 
     FROM FINANCIAL F   
      INNER JOIN BDE.LOAN_V a ON F.LOAN_NUMBER = A.LOAN_NUMBER)
     WHERE A.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE> 0
        GROUP BY F.LOAN_NUMBER 
        ORDER BY F.LOAN_NUMBER,   


FETCH ONLY WITH UR ')
```

Here is the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "A" was found following "BER)           WHERE".  Expected tokens may include:  "FROM".  SQLSTATE=42601
>   ".
>   Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you have a naked query, which is not uncommon in Microsoft SQL Server.  A simplified version of your linked query looks like this:

```
SELECT (subquery), (subquery) WHERE ...conditions...
```

In DB2, you must have a `FROM` clause in any query.  Microsoft and some other SQL vendors permit a `SELECT` with no `FROM` clause, but this isn't standard SQL. In this case, DB2 conforms to the standard.

---

Second thing I notice:

```
IF(SELECT(OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TempFile))) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempFile
```

Do you need to close that quoted string?

Comment: typing error on my part. Thanks for spotting that. Got it working!~ SELECT F.LOAN_NUMBER, SUM(MORTGAGOR_NET_PAY_AMOUNT) + SUM(MORTGAGOR_OTHER_INCOME_AMOUNT) AS IncomeTotal, SUM(EXP_CHILD_CARE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_FOOD_AMOUNT) + 
SUM(EXP_LIFE_INSURANCE_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TRANSPORTATION_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_TUITION_AMOUNT)+ SUM(EXP_USER_1_AMOUNT) + sUM(EXP_USER_2_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_USER_3_AMOUNT) + SUM(EXP_UTILITIES_AMOUNT)AS ExpenseTotal FROM FINANCIAL F INNER JOIN LOANa ON F.LOAN_NUMBER = a.LOAN_NUMBER WHERE a.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE> 0 GROUP BY F.LOAN_NUMBER ORDER BY f.LOAN_NUMBER

Comment: What, you never heard of copy & paste?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`= A.LOAN_NUMBER)
     WHERE A.FIRST_PRINCIPAL_BALANCE> 0` - that bracket looks out of place.